# Ionic formControlName how to bind with ngModal?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a from group, inside the ion-input i have a formControlName, by using this formControlName, my ngModal is not bind to it.

Anyone know how to bind the ngModal with formControlName ??

Thanks in advance. !!

```
 <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item [ngClass]="{'error-border':!myForm.controls.telephone.valid && myForm.controls.telephone.touched}">
          <ion-label fixed>Contact</ion-label>
          <ion-input maxlength="10" type="tel" placeholder="0124037337" formControlName="telephone" text-right></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="myForm.controls.telephone.hasError('required') && myForm.controls.telephone.touched">
            <p>This Field is Required !! </p>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="myForm.controls.telephone.hasError('pattern') && myForm.controls.telephone.touched">
            <p>Only Number is Allowed !! </p>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="myForm.controls.telephone.hasError('minlength') && myForm.controls.telephone.touched">
            <p>Telephone Number is Invalid !! </p>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

After I add the ngModal inside it, it gives me this error

```
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item [ngClass]="{'error-border':!myForm.controls.telephone.valid && myForm.controls.telephone.touched}">
          <ion-label fixed>Contact</ion-label>
          <ion-input maxlength="10" type="tel" placeholder="0124037337" text-right formControlName="telephone" [{ngModal}]="telHere"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="myForm.controls.telephone.hasError('required') && myForm.controls.telephone.touched">
            <p>This Field is Required !! </p>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="myForm.controls.telephone.hasError('pattern') && myForm.controls.telephone.touched">
            <p>Only Number is Allowed !! </p>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="myForm.controls.telephone.hasError('minlength') && myForm.controls.telephone.touched">
            <p>Telephone Number is Invalid !! </p>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

[image]

Comment: Just add your ngModel normaly. What wrong with it?

Comment: I added normal, and it give me error, I edited and post the error in the question.

Comment: It is not `ngModal`. It is `ngModel`. You should use like that: `[(ngModel)]="telHere"`

Comment: OMG...thanks a lot !! ahahahahaha OMG what a mistake i make..thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Please don't mix template driven form with reactive form any way, choose one over the other ;)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for two way binding in Angular is `[(ngModel)]="telHere"`. You can remember this syntax by the name "banana in a box", because it looks like there is a banana () in an box [].